# ng-change directive triggered before model is updated when clicking uib-button-radio element

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

Here's a plnkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/bJ6LSR7fAY9mlvqBzDUw?p=preview

I'm using uib-button-radio elements to toggle the active filter on an ng-repeat.

```
  <div ng-controller="ButtonsCtrl as $ctrl">
    <h4>Radio</h4>
    <pre>Model: {{$ctrl.radioModel}}</pre>
    <div class="btn-group">
      <label class="btn btn-primary" ng-change="$ctrl.do()" ng-model="$ctrl.radioModel" uib-btn-radio="'Left'">Left</label>
      <label class="btn btn-primary" ng-change="$ctrl.do()" ng-model="$ctrl.radioModel" uib-btn-radio="'Middle'">Middle</label>
      <label class="btn btn-primary" ng-change="$ctrl.do()" ng-model="$ctrl.radioModel" uib-btn-radio="'Right'">Right</label>
    </div>

    <p ng-repeat="item in $ctrl.filtered = ($ctrl.collection | filter: { Value: $ctrl.radioModel } )">{{item | json}}</p>

    <p>First filtered item: {{$ctrl.active | json}}</p>
```

ng-change/ng-click function:

```
  ctrl.do = function() {
    ctrl.active = ctrl.filtered[0];
  }
```

When the selected filter changes, and subsequently the collection is updated, I want to select the first item in the filtered collection. However it appears that the ng-change/ng-click function is firing before the collection is updated by the filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is apply the filtering logic in JavaScript instead of in the markup.

In the HTML, change the `ng-repeat` expression to just:

```
<p ng-repeat="item in $ctrl.filtered">{{item | json}}</p>
```

In the controller, inject `$filter`:

```
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('ButtonsCtrl', function ($scope, $filter) {
```

Initialize the filtered array:

```
ctrl.filtered = [];
```

And do the filtering in the `do` change handler:

```
ctrl.do = function() {
    ctrl.filtered = $filter('filter')(ctrl.collection, { Value: ctrl.radioModel });
    ctrl.active = ctrl.filtered[0];
}
```

Comment: my actual code is a bit more complex than the sample i provided and requires chaining filters but this put me on the right path, along with [todd-motto link](https://toddmotto.com/use-controller-filters-to-prevent-digest-performance-issues/)